# CASE statement causing an error

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

```
declare @JANORG int;
declare @FEBORG int;
declare @MARORG int;
declare @APRORG int;
declare @MAYORG int; 
declare @JUNORG int;
declare @JULORG int;
declare @AUGORG int;
declare @SEPORG int;
declare @OCTORG int;
declare @NOVORG int;
declare @DECORG int;

select 
    p.orgid, p.projid, bomitem.fk_itemid, p.budgetyear,
    SUM(cast((bom.component_attachrate*bomitem.itemqty*@JANORG)/100 AS INT)),
    SUM(cast((bom.component_attachrate*bomitem.itemqty*@FEBORG)/100 AS INT)),
    SUM(cast((bom.component_attachrate*bomitem.itemqty*@MARORG)/100 AS INT)),
    SUM(cast((bom.component_attachrate*bomitem.itemqty*@APRORG)/100 AS INT)),
    SUM(cast((bom.component_attachrate*bomitem.itemqty*@MAYORG)/100 AS INT)),
    SUM(cast((bom.component_attachrate*bomitem.itemqty*@JUNORG)/100 AS INT)),
    SUM(cast((bom.component_attachrate*bomitem.itemqty*@JULORG)/100 AS INT)),
    SUM(cast((bom.component_attachrate*bomitem.itemqty*@AUGORG)/100 AS INT)),
    SUM(cast((bom.component_attachrate*bomitem.itemqty*@SEPORG)/100 AS INT)),
    SUM(cast((bom.component_attachrate*bomitem.itemqty*@OCTORG)/100 AS INT)),
    SUM(cast((bom.component_attachrate*bomitem.itemqty*@NOVORG)/100 AS INT)),
    SUM(cast((bom.component_attachrate*bomitem.itemqty*@DECORG)/100 AS INT)) 
from 
    REF_VHF_COMPONENT bom, VHF_COMPONENT_ITEMS bomitem,
    VHF_PRJFCAST v, VHF_SYSGEN_PROJ p, VHF_ORGPT o 
where  
    bom.pk_ID = bomitem.fk_bomid
    and p.budgetyear = o.budgetyear 
    and CASE @JANORG WHEN v.JANORG = '0' THEN v.JANORG WHEN v.JANAREA = '0'                THEN     v.JANAREA ELSE p.JANORG END,
 CASE @FEBORG WHEN v.FEBORG <> '0' THEN v.FEBORG WHEN v.FEBAREA <> '0' THEN        v.FEBAREA ELSE p.FEBORG END,
          CASE @MARORG WHEN v.MARORG <> '0' THEN v.MARORG WHEN v.MARAREA <> '0' THEN v.MARAREA ELSE p.MARORG END,
 CASE @APRORG WHEN v.APRORG <> '0' THEN v.APRORG WHEN v.APRAREA <> '0' THEN v.APRAREA ELSE p.APRORG END,
 CASE @MAYORG WHEN v.MAYORG <> '0' THEN v.MAYORG WHEN v.MAYAREA <> '0' THEN v.MAYAREA ELSE p.MAYORG END,
 CASE @JUNORG WHEN v.JUNORG <> '0' THEN v.JUNORG WHEN v.JUNAREA <> '0' THEN v.JUNAREA ELSE p.JUNORG END,
 CASE @JULORG WHEN v.JULORG <> '0' THEN v.JULORG WHEN v.JULAREA <> '0' THEN v.JULAREA ELSE p.JULORG END,
 CASE @AUGORG WHEN v.AUGORG <> '0' THEN v.AUGORG WHEN v.AUGAREA <> '0' THEN v.AUGAREA ELSE p.AUGORG END,
 CASE @SEPORG WHEN v.SEPORG <> '0' THEN v.SEPORG WHEN v.SEPAREA <> '0' THEN v.SEPAREA ELSE p.SEPORG END,
 CASE @OCTORG WHEN v.OCTORG <> '0' THEN v.OCTORG WHEN v.OCTAREA <> '0' THEN v.OCTAREA ELSE p.OCTORG END,
 CASE @NOVORG WHEN v.NOVORG <> '0' THEN v.NOVORG WHEN v.NOVAREA <> '0' THEN v.NOVAREA ELSE p.NOVORG END,
 CASE @DECORG WHEN v.DECORG <> '0' THEN v.DECORG WHEN v.DECAREA <> '0' THEN v.DECAREA ELSE p.DECORG END 
group by 
    bomitem.fk_itemid, p.orgid, p.projid, bomitem.fk_itemid, p.budgetyear
```

I am getting an error that incorrect syntax of case statement*

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense and I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Just taking the first `CASE` expression, ignoring the others, and assuming `JANORG` is '0', we get the following `WHERE` clause: `bom.pk_ID = bomitem.fk_bomid AND p.budgetyear = o.budgetyear AND v.JANORG`. That's incomplete. What was meant to be *done* with `v.JANORG`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` expression doesn't follow either of the two proper formats.  Either you can identify the value you want to compare to once:

```
CASE col1 WHEN 'dog' THEN 1
          WHEN 'cat' THEN 2
          WHEN 'horse' THEN 3
END
```

Or you can use the more flexible format, where each `WHEN` has comprehensive criteria that can reference different fields:

```
CASE WHEN col1 = 'dog' THEN 1
     WHEN col2 = 'horse' THEN 1
     WHEN col3 = 'cat' THEN 2
END
```

It's unclear what you are attempting to do with your `CASE` expressions.  If you want to filter using them, you need to evaluate the `CASE` expression against something else:

```
WHERE CASE ... END = @variable1
  AND CASE ... END = @variable2
```

Comment: See I am trying to store these values in a variable because i would need them in my next statement and if I am taking this CASE  WHEN v.JANORG <> '0' THEN v.JANORG WHEN v.JANAREA <> '0' THEN v.JANAREA ELSE p.JANORG END =@JANORG that means i need value of janorg so that i can use them in my calculation

Comment: I still don't quite follow what you're after, but the expressions are malformed as well as the `WHERE` clause, `CASE` expressions have to be formatted in one of the two ways I mentioned, and the `WHERE` clause can't have a comma separated list of conditions. If you are trying to set the values of those variables, it would take place in a `SET` or `SELECT`, but you can't store multiple rows in an `INT`.  Perhaps you could show where you are trying to make use of these variables?